# Why are dates in match aggregate query being ignored?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to run an aggregation statement in my mongo db. I have a document whose structure is (at least) as follows:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId,
   "date": ISODate,
   "keywordGroupId": NumberLong,
   "ranking": NumberLong,
}
```

I would like to run an aggregation statement that aggregates the 'ranking' field for a given 'keywordGroupId' and a given 'date' interval.

I have been trying with the following aggregate command:

```
{ 
    aggregate : "KeywordHistory", 
    pipeline : [
        { $match: { keywordGroupId: 75 , "$date": {$gte: ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"), $lt: ISODate("2013-02-01T00:00:00.0Z")}} },
        { $group: { _id: { null }, count: { $sum: "$ranking" } } }
    ]
}
```

This command executes without errors and returns a result. If I try to change the value for the 'keywordGroupId' field, the command returns a different value, so I assume that the $match statement works for that field (NumberLong). Though, if I change the 'date' range and I specify a time interval for which I don't have any data in the database, it still returns a result (I would actually expect an empty result set). So I have to assume that the $match statement is ignoring the date interval specified.

Can anyone help me with this point?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Remove the `$` prefix on the `$date` field of your `$match`:

```
{ $match: { 
    keywordGroupId: 75, 
    date: {$gte: ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"), $lt: ISODate("2013-02-01T00:00:00.0Z")}
}},
```

You only use the `$` prefix when the field name is used in a value, not as a key.

Comment: I've already tried without the `$` but it doesn't work. Actually, if I remove it, the query always returns an empty result set (even if I use a date interval which is in the database).

Comment: I would like the following two documents to be included: `{
   "_id": ObjectId("511e2dca73ff275f250002e9"),
   "date": ISODate("2013-01-06T00:00:00.0Z"),
   "keywordGroupId": NumberLong(75),
   "ranking": NumberLong(13)
} and {
   "_id": ObjectId("511e2dca73ff275f250002e8"),
   "keywordGroupId": NumberInt(75),
   "date": ISODate("2013-01-15T00:00:00.0Z"),
   "ranking": NumberInt(11)
}`

Comment: Though, I don't want the following one in my result: `{
   "_id": ObjectId("511e2dca73ff275f250002e8"),
   "keywordGroupId": NumberInt(75),
   "date": ISODate("2012-12-16T00:00:00.0Z"),
   "ranking": NumberInt(11)
}` . If I run the aggregate command above (with the $date), it also returns the document here above even though it shouldn't be included as the date is not in the desired/expressed time range.

Comment: @Marco That doc you don't want included has the same `_id` as the 1-15 one.  But after fixing that, the aggregation worked as it should, returning just the two docs.

Comment: Sorry, for convenience, I had copied it and only changed the field date from one of the documents that should be included in the result. I just run the aggregate command again to check if the _id are all unique and they are. Here is a document that shouldn't be in my result set (I want data only for january) but it is still included in it: `{
       "_id": ObjectId("511e2dc773ff275f25000253"),
       "keywordGroupId": NumberInt(75),
       "date": ISODate("2013-02-06T00: 00: 00.0Z"),
       "ranking": NumberInt(1)
    }`

Comment: @Marco Hmm...I'm not sure what I'm doing differently than you, but that one gets excluded just fine too.

Comment: how are you running the command? I'm using RockMongo v1.1.2 and run the command in the section 'command'

Comment: I have installed mongo version 2.2.3 .. and you?

Comment: @Marco I'm using a little node.js program and mongo 2.2.3.

Comment: I tried to run the command from a PHP application and it's now working. I tried with both "date" and "$date" and only the first one is working, as you said. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes ISodate does not works . so in Case  if you want to match date using only "one" date the best way is:---

ex:-- Let a schema be:---

```
    var storeOrder = new Schema({
    store_name:{type:String, required:true},
    date :{type:Date ,default:moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')},
    orders : [{
    vegetable : String,
    quantity : Number,
    price:Number
     }]
});
```

```
mongoose.model('storeorder',storeOrder);
```

now to aggregate by matching date :--

```
storeOrder.aggregate([$match:{date :new Date("2016-12-26T00:00:00.000Z")} ])
```

**It is must to use `new Date("2016-12-26T00:00:00.000z")` instead of `Date("2016-12-26T00:00:00.000z") because Date(your_date) !== new Date(your_date)`.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

The aggregate expects a Javascript Date Object and doesn't work otherwise.

> ```
> new Date();
> new Date(year, month, day);
> ```

Please note the month start with 0 and not 1 (Your January is 0 and December 11)