# Mongoose/Mongo Count Objects in Array of References by createdAt

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

On my user collection, I have a two fields like this:

```
  assignedTickets: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Ticket',
      index: true,
    },
  ],
  resolvedTickets: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Ticket',
      index: true,
    },
  ],
```

For each of these fields, I'm trying to get a count of the objects based on each object's created date. For example, for 2018-05-03 I want to know how many tickets were created on that date.

I attempted this:

```
const start = new Date();
start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
const end = new Date();
end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

userSchema.statics.assignedToday = function () {
  return this.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'tickets', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'assignee_id', as: 'tickets',
      },
    },
    { $unwind: '$tickets' },
    { $match: { createdAt: { $gte: start, $lt: end } } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          year: { $year: '$createdAt' },
          month: { $month: '$createdAt' },
          day: { $dayOfMonth: '$createdAt' },
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ]);
};
```

But I only receive back an empty array `[]`

If I comment out the $match part of the pipeline, I get:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2018,
      "month": 5,
      "day": 2
    },
    "count": 178
  }
]
```

But this is a total count of ALL tickets (not just assigned) and the data is coming back for just May 2 (which is the date the Ticket collection was created).

Here is an example of a user document:

```
{
  "assignedTickets": [
    "5ae9c2d59c7fcb540cca0b9e",
    "5ae9c3649c7fcb540cca0ba0",
    "5ae9c3849c7fcb540cca0ba2",
    ...
  ],
  "resolvedTickets": [
    "5ae9c2d59c7fcb540cca0b9d",
    "5ae9c2d59c7fcb540cca0b9e",
    "5ae9c3299c7fcb540cca0b9f",
    ...
  ],
  "_id": "5ae763a6ed455639802e8f1a",
  "firstName": "NAME",
  "lastName": "LASTNAME",
  "email": "EMAIL",
  "createdAt": "2018-04-30T18:42:46.582Z",
  "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T15:29:13.955Z",
  "__v": 0,
}
```

Here is an example of a ticket document:

```
{
  "_id": "5ae9c2d59c7fcb540cca0b9e",
  "ticket_id": 119472,
  "type": "resolved",
  "status": "Solved",
  "assignee_email": "EMAIL",
  "createdAt": "2018-05-01T13:53:25.639Z",
  "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T04:06:22.852Z",
  "__v": 0,
  "assignee_id": "5ae763a6ed455639802e8f1a"
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask for a clarification? It would be useful if you could [edit] your question to include an example or two of the data which you're querying - for example a user document which was created today?

Comment: Hi Vince! I've updated the question by adding an example of a user document and a ticket document. Many thanks!

Comment: Another tip for debugging; the logic in the $group stage of your aggregation is only concerned with data in the user document - so you could temporarily comment out the $lookup and $unwind stages, to focus on what the $group stage is doing.

Comment: I think the match query `{ $match: { createdAt: { $gte: start, $lt: end } } },` is running on users collections. It should be `{ $match: { 'tickets.createdAt': { $gte: start, $lt: end } } },`.

Comment: Vince, I commented out the lookup and unwind stages of the pipeline, and the data that comes back reports the number of users created per date. For example:   {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2018,
      "month": 5,
      "day": 2
    },
    "count": 2
  }
Which is correctly showing the number of users that were added on that date.

Comment: Mandar, I updated the match stage on your suggestion, but it just returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the correct syntax to return the results correctly:

```
const start = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
const end = new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

userSchema.statics.getAssigned = function () {
  return this.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'tickets',
        localField: 'assignedTickets',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'assigned_tickets',
      },
    },
    { $unwind: '$assigned_tickets' },
    { $match: { 'assigned_tickets.createdAt': { $gte: new Date(start), $lt: new Date(end) } } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          year: { $year: '$assigned_tickets.createdAt' },
          month: { $month: '$assigned_tickets.createdAt' },
          day: { $dayOfMonth: '$assigned_tickets.createdAt' },
          _id: '$assigned_tickets.assignee_id' },
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
};
```

There were a few problems in my original function.

First, on the lookup, I was referencing the `_id` field for localField, but that should have been `assignedTickets` (specifically for getting the assigned tickets), and the `foreignField` that was `assignee_id` should have been `_id`.

The second issue was the dates passed in to the $match stage, which [this SO question help me answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024383/mongo-dates-in-match-aggregate-query-seem-to-be-ignored).

Finally, the $match stage needed to reference the `assigned_tickets` alias from the $lookup stage, which mandar helped me realize.