# Mongo match aggregate not working with date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm using `mongoose` and the following works just fine.

```
const TODAY = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const todaysFoos = await Foo.find({updatedAt: { $gte: TODAY }, someField: { $ne: '' } });
```

Where `updatedAt` is created/updated by using the  `timestamps: true` in the `Mongoose Model`

However, I'm unable to get this to work with an `aggregate`
`const mapping = { alias: "$someField" };`

```
 const pipeline = [
    { $match: { updatedAt: { $gte: TODAY }, someField: { $ne: '' } } },
    { $project: mapping }
];

const todaysFoos = await Foo.aggregate(pipeline);
```

I keep getting nothing back from the aggregate whereas the first `find` works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the query returning some results without the `$project` stage ?

Comment: No, it is not. I'm thinking it has something to do with the `match`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and for anyone looking for a solution.

You can check out [Mongo: dates in match aggregate query seem to be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024383/mongo-dates-in-match-aggregate-query-seem-to-be-ignored)

Apparently, match works with `new Date(your_date)`

Therefore the logic will be

```
const TODAY = new Date();
const pipeline = [
    { $match: { updatedAt: { $gte: TODAY }, someField: { $ne: '' } } },
    { $project: mapping }
];
const todaysFoos = await Foo.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do

```
let TODAY = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
TODAY = new Date(TODAY);
```

I don't know this is needed for `$match` but it works in `find`. Does anybody know?