# MongoDB: Is there another way to match by date other than ISODate in an aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My question is relatively simple. I have a collection of documents that look like this

```
    {
     _id:"61f52b609f97a100092842f2"
     timestampISO:2022-01-29T11:56:14.000+00:00
    }
```

The timestampISO is a date type.

Is there a way to match by date without using ISODate("...") as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025828) ? I am trying not to use ISODate('') as I would actually like to save the pipeline as a string in Mongo but that is not important right now.

I would like to have a match like this

```
$match: {
   timestampISO: {
       $gte: {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '2022-01-01T11:56:14.000+00:00',
          }
       },
       $lte: {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '2022-01-29T11:56:14.000+00:00',
          }
       },
   }
}
```

which does not work. It seems as though ISODate() seems to be the only way? Is this correct?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is your reason not using ISODate()?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I actually want to store the pipeline as a string in Mongo. I then will need to fetch the pipeline and parse it using JSON.parse(pipeline) but unfortunately ISODate() will need to be wrapped in quotes which means it won't work.

Comment: Yes, `ISODate()` is available only within the mongo shell. Then maybe the native way: `{ timestampISO: { $gt: { "$date:" '2022-01-01T11:56:14.000+00:00' } } }`

Comment: I think in your case there is a much simpler solution. Use `EJSON.stringify` and `EJSON.parse`, they support `Date` objects and you don't have to take care about any constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ISODate()` is just an alias in the Mongo shell for `new Date()`.

`{ $dateFromString: { dateString: '2022-01-01T11:56:14.000+00:00' } }` is more or less the same, however you have to use

```
{
   $match: {
      $expr: {
         $gte: [
            "$timestampISO",
            { $dateFromString: { dateString: '2022-01-01T11:56:14+00:00' } }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

or maybe a bit simpler:

```
{ $match: 
    {$expr: {$gte: ["$timestampISO", { $toDate: '2022-01-01T11:56:14.000+00:00' } ] }}
}
```

Comment: Using $expr was the trick. Thank you for that. I then did the same thing for the $lte as well.